# 4% prob per month, what is prob per year?

Tags: probability

A certain event can in principle occur unlimited number of times, unrelated.

Q1: Now, if the event has 4% probability of occuring each month, what is the probability "P1" of it occuring once or more during a year? 
-I think it has to be somehow less than 12*4%=48%, because there would not be 25*4%=100% probability of it happening in 25 months... :-)
-But how to actually calculate?

Q2: And if we know the above probability: to find the probability "P2" of it happening twice or more in a year, would I be roughly correct by taking the square of the above P1 - (i.e. P2=P1^2)?

Comment: Do you mean "for each month  the probability of occurring is 4%" or (as it is written now) "the probability that the event will occur each month is 4%"?

Comment: Not native speaker, but I think it's the way I wrote it. Over the last 10 years (120 months), a certain event occurred 5 times. So I boldly state that the chance of it occuring at any given month is 5/120 = approx 4%. I then want to say something about the chance of it happening at least once within the coming year, and the chance of it happening twice within the coming year.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.** You have 12 identical and independent experiments, each is either success $P(S)=0.04$ or failure $P(F)=1-0.04=0.96$. 
Thus the binomial distribution is appropriate for the total number of successes $X$,
$$P(X=k)= \binom{12}{k}0.04^{k}\times0.96^{12-k}.$$

Comment: Thank you ever so much! Sorry for my low level, could you possibly explain the variable "k" plus the notation "(a over b)" - not a normal fraction I take it?

Comment: @tihelles  The notation $\binom{n}{k}$ is the number of ways of unordered selections of $k$ objects from $n$ objects.  $\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n - k)!}$.